# Unreal doesn't see Visual Studio 2019

Tags: unreal-4, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed, with all of the tools mentioned in the Unreal documentation installed, and when I try to create a C++ project in Unreal Engine, I get "No compiler was found. In order to use a C++ template, you must first install Visual Studio 2017.".

I don't have VS 2017 and would prefer not to get it because I'm using a metered connection. According to the Unreal documentation, VS 2019 is indeed supported but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Did you include the Unreal Engine Installer in VS2019?

Comment: @Stephen Yes I did. Did Unreal recognize VS 2019 for you?

Comment: I'm still using VS2017 but that was the first reason I could think of why Unreal wouldn't see it.

Comment: Isn't there a way for you to install the 2017 version so you can use the 2019 version?